# Android progress bar style syntax

Tags: android

In a progress bar definition the style is defined as

```
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
```

I'm not clear on how this syntax works. Can someone explain this syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That syntax is used to reference a system style attribute, and it's similar to the syntax used to reference a resource predefined by the Android system: whereas in the general resource case you use e.g. `@android:drawable/ic_media_play` to reference a Drawable represented by the file `ic_media_play.png` in the value of an `android:src` attribute for the `ImageButton` UI element included in an XML layout, the attribute reference is built using a `?` instead of a `@`, but for the rest is composed following the same rules and works in the same way.

In particular, attributes are usually stored in `res/values/attrs.xml`, where you can find (looking at the system resources stored in the Android SDK) the following

```
<attr name="progressBarStyleHorizontal" format="reference" />
```

indicating that the attribute is a reference to some other resource. The style attribute is defined in `res/values/themes.xml` in the following fashion:

```
<item name="progressBarStyleHorizontal">
    @android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal
</item>
```

which is indeed a reference to the style `Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal` in the system `res/values/styles.xml` as already described by another answer.

Note that, in contexts when the system knows to expect a reference to an attribute resource, you may even omit the resource type (i.e. the `attr/` part), leading to a syntax such as:

```
android:textColor="?android:textColorSecondary"
```

You may find slightly more information on the [Android developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ReferencesToThemeAttributes)

Answer (score 1):

android:attr means this style is picked from frameworks of android. So if you browse the source of styles.xml from frameworks http://bit.ly/yBC5pM and search 
progressBarStyleHorizontal, You can see it inherits from Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal

> ```
> <style name="Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal" parent="@style/Widget.ProgressBar">
>     <item name="maxHeight">20.0dip</item>
>     <item name="indeterminateOnly">false</item>
>     <item name="indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/progress_indeterminate_horizontal</item>
>     <item name="progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_horizontal</item>
>     <item name="minHeight">20.0dip</item>
> </style>
> ```

All the above properties + properties from Widget.Progressbar(Since its parent is this) will get inherited to your Progressbar.

Comment: My question is related to the syntax in which the style is defined 

"style="?android:attr/"

Comment: like guilio said, syntax part can be found at the link provided by him